# FractionallySizedBox with max size in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this widget showing a ball in the middle of the screen:

```
FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.5,
        child: Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Helpers.hexToColor(color),
            border: new Border.all(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
```

For mobile I'm displaying this as 50% of the width, which is cool, but not for tablet. Here I'd like to set a max of XXXpx to avoid a huge ball in big tablets.

I could do something like this: 
`widthFactor: getSize()`

And:

```
double getSize() {
 final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 if (width  > 500) {
   return 0.2;
 }
 // other checks
 ...
 return 0.5; // the default one
}
```

But I'd like to know if there's a simpler widget for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap your `FractionallySizedBox` with `ConstrainedBox`

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 50), // max height in px
  child: FractionallySizedBox(
    widthFactor: 0.5,
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Helpers.hexToColor(color),
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 5.0,
        ),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: I guess that if I need more than 2 sizes (dynamic and max) I'd need to go for my option, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
      FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.9,
        child: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 70), // max height in px
              child: Text('abcabcabcabcabcabc')),
        ),
      ),
```

you have to first use `FractionallySizedBox`, and then `Center`, and then `ConstrainedBox` if you don't use `Center` or use `ConstrainedBox` first, you will get this behaviour where maxWidth/maxHeight is not working at all